# Hibernate Native Query fails but SQL Query works

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have this query using hibernate:

```
@Query(value = "BEGIN SET @rank = 1; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results "
        + "SELECT User.userId, User.username, @rank FROM User WHERE User.username = :searchString ;"

        + "SET @rank = 2; INSERT INTO results (SELECT User.userId, User.username, @rank FROM Following "
        + "JOIN User ON Following.followsId = User.userId " + "JOIN UserProfile ON UserProfile.userProfileId = User.userProfileId "
        + "WHERE Following.userId = :userId AND User.username LIKE :searchString "
        + "ORDER BY UserProfile.followsCount DESC); "

        + "SET @rank = 3; INSERT INTO results (SELECT User.userId, User.username, @rank FROM User "
        + "JOIN UserProfile ON UserProfile.userProfileId = User.userProfileId "
        + "WHERE User.username LIKE :searchString ORDER BY UserProfile.followsCount DESC); "

        + "SELECT User.* FROM results JOIN User ON User.userId = results.userId ORDER BY @rank DESC LIMIT 50; "
        + "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE results; END;", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> findLike(@Param("searchString") String searchString, @Param("userId") Long userId);
```

When I run it, i'm told that it could not extract the result set (by JUNIT) and in the console

> 16:32:24.554 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @rank = 1; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results SELECT User.userId, ' at line 1

I turned hibernate.show_sql=true and even ran the query that was logged to the console using mysqlworkbench and it works.

Note that this query is running in a interface that is defined as such:

```
public interface IUserJpaDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>
```

Any ideas why it works in MySqlWorkbench and not in hibernate?

Comment: You can use `begin;` or `begin transaction;`, but `begin set` is invalid syntax. Try adding a semicolon.

Comment: @coladict still the same errors